# Why am i getting a,b,c instead of actual values in output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, insert

```
N = int(input())
q = []
x=list(input())
a,b,c=x[0],x[1],x[2]                                  
q.insert(0,'a')
q.insert(0,'c')
q.insert(1,'b')
print(q)`
```

i want output as [6, 5, 10] how can i specifically take value from a list and insert it into another also is there a way with x not at all being a list

Comment: 1- what is the input? 2- What is the logic? 3- `q.insert(0,'a')` here you request to insert the string `'a'`, not the value reference by `a`, 4- `list(input())` is probably not doing what you expect

Answer (score 0):

You need split your input and change the listName.insert values with variables.

'a' is different form a. The first is a character and the second is a variable.

```
q = []
x=list(input("Enter three values separated with space: ").split())
a,b,c=x[0],x[1],x[2] 
q.insert(0,a)
q.insert(0,c)
q.insert(1,b)
print(q)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter three values separated with space: 
1 2 3
['3', '2', '1']
```

Another thing, N is an unused variable.